# Does ordering of parameters in a method annotated by Spring MVC @RequestMapping matter?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have the following method of which, ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument() throws a BindException:

```
public String postMethod(HttpServletRequest request, 
                         HttpSession session,
                         @SessionParam(value="key") Visitor visitor,                                  
                         @Validated(CreateAccountForm.EnterPersonalInfo.class) @ModelAttribute(CreateUserForm.ATTRIBUTE_KEY) CreateUserForm form,
                         Model model,
                         Errors errors) throws Exception
{
//Code here
}
```

When I move the Model parameter anywhere BEFORE the param containing the @ModelAttribute param, everything works fine.

So why does the location of my Model parameter in the method declaration cause such a problem? Am I using @ModelAttribute incorrectly?

Comment: Typically, no, ordering of handler method parameters does not matter. Of the built-in `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` implementations, I think only the one for `Errors`/`BindingResult` cares about order. That's what you are seeing.

Comment: That's [`ErrorsMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/ErrorsMethodArgumentResolver.html): _An `Errors` method argument is expected to appear immediately after the model attribute in the method signature. It is resolved by expecting the last two attributes added to the model to be the model attribute and its `BindingResult`._